# Require the main app "package.json"

Tags: browserify, package.json

I'm making a small web app that will be served both via npm and the git repo.

I'd like to read (via Browserify) the "package.json" of the main app, which would be:

- Via Git fork:

  ```
  my-app
  |-package.json <-- there it is
  |-src
  |--app.js <-- ('require from ../package.json')
  ```
- Via NPM

  ```
  user-app
  |-package.json <-- it's still here
  |-node_modules
  |--my-module
  |---src
  |----app.js <-- but this guy is now too far ('require from ../../../package.json')
  ```

This could still be different if the user has a custom package path. doing `require('package.json')` doesn't work.

Is there a way I could make sure I'll reach this file?

Comment: maybe via webpack?